# How can I build a DataTable schema from schema.ini with special characters

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to convert a schema.ini file (created by a csv export) to a typed data table in c#.  I'm having troubles with getting the table names from the file.  The schema.ini looks like this:

```
[MyTableÄ.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
CharacterSet=1201
Format=CSVDelimited
CurrencyThousandSymbol=,
DecimalSymbol=.
Col1="Id" Integer
Col2="Subscriber Equipment" Char ...
```

however when I use the following snippet to read the section names I get `MyTableÃ„.csv` instead of `MyTableÄ.csv`.

```
public string[] SectionNames()
        {
        uint MAX_BUFFER = 32767;
        IntPtr pReturnedString = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)MAX_BUFFER);
        uint bytesReturned = GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(pReturnedString, MAX_BUFFER, path);
        if (bytesReturned == 0)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pReturnedString);
            return null;
        }
        string local = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pReturnedString, (int) bytesReturned);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pReturnedString);
        //use of Substring below removes terminating null for split
        return local.Substring(0, local.Length - 1).Split('\0');
    }
```

I've tried the charactersets: `20127, ANSI, 65001, Unicode, and 1201` to no avail.  Ideas?  Workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Save your file with Unicode.

2) Import `GetPrivateProfileSectionNames` in an alternative way to meet your requirement.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="GetPrivateProfileSectionNamesW", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(IntPtr lpszReturnBuffer, uint nSize, string lpFileName);
```

3) Change the call of `PtrToStringAnsi` to `PtrToStringUni`.

These steps achieve what you want, the entire code is

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="GetPrivateProfileSectionNamesW", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(IntPtr lpszReturnBuffer, uint nSize, string lpFileName);

public string[] SectionNames() {
    uint MAX_BUFFER=32767;
    IntPtr pReturnedString=Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)MAX_BUFFER);
    uint bytesReturned=GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(pReturnedString, MAX_BUFFER, path);
    if(bytesReturned==0) {
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pReturnedString);
        return null;
    }
    string local=Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pReturnedString, (int)bytesReturned);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pReturnedString);
    //use of Substring below removes terminating null for split
    return local.Substring(0, local.Length-1).Split('\0');
}
```

BTW, your code appears [[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/netfxbcl/thread/c4168505-ab40-477c-84ad-3e06b4e18438)] on MSDN forum.

Comment: Thank you!  I assumed the code had been copied from somewhere else but I didn't know the source.  I've update how we write the schema.ini to be Unicode encoding and made the changes you suggested and everything is working well.